# AttributeError: function' object has no attribute 'linreg'

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and programming  and am working my way through "Machine Learning: An Algorithmic Perspective."  I was told to normalise data, seperate it into training and testing data, recover the beta vector, and then use the sum-of-least squares error.  I keep getting,

File "/Users/shaune/Dropbox/Shaune PhD/auto-mpg.py", line 34, in 
    beta=linreg.linreg(trainin,traintgt)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'linreg'

when running the following:

```
import os
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
import linreg

os.chdir('/Users/shaune/Dropbox/Shaune PhD')
auto=np.loadtxt('auto-mpg.data.txt',comments='"')

#normalise the data
auto=(auto-auto.mean(axis=0))/auto.var(axis=0)

#seperate the training and testing data
trainin=auto[::2,:8]
testin=auto[1::2,:8]
traintgt=auto[::2,1:2]
testtgt=auto[1::2,1:2]

#recover the beta vector
def linreg(trainin,traintgt):
    trainin=np.concatenate((trainin,-np.ones((np.shape(trainin)[0],1))),axis=1)
    beta=np.dot(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(trainin),trainin)),np.transpose(trainin)),traintgt)
    traintgt=np.dot(trainin, beta)

#sum of squares error to get predicted values on test set (want small values)
beta=linreg.linreg(trainin,traintgt)
testin=concatenate((testin,-np.ones((np.shape(testin)[0],1))),axis=1)
testout=dot(testin,beta)
error=sum((testout-testtgt)**2)
print error
```

Please help!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of this function

```
def linreg(trainin,traintgt):
```

is overwriting the name `linreg` that you imported with

```
import linreg
```

Rename the function.  The comment says `recover the beta vector`, so perhaps a better name is `recover_beta`.  That is, change the `def` statement to

```
def recover_beta(trainin,traintgt):
```

You'll probably want to add a `return` statement to the function while you are at it.  Currently it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for that.  That worked!  But I don't understand what is going on now.  I thought I was using linreg to come up with a way of separating the data.  When I change the name, it doesn't seem like I ever reference those lines again.  What is it giving me?  I've also tried return but it says: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.